# How to find a missing file from a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file, directory

I have a directory in which 'wav' files are stored. These files's names are sequential in order ie 1.wav, 2.wav, 3.wav.... etc.

I have to find out the missing wav file, like if 3.wav is missing then I have to find out that and the name '3' should given to a variable.

How can I do this?

Comment: Simple loop will do. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Sahadow  I did like this files = Directory.GetFiles(root_dir, "*.wav");
        int number_of_files = files.Length;
        int[] file_name = new int[number_of_files];
        
        for (int ix = 0; ix < files.Length; ix++)
        {
             file_name[ix] = Convert.ToInt32(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[ix]));
        }

Comment: Please add this to your question and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: @Smitha - please see my answer, it may help you.  You can adjust length to files.Length and path to: Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple loop and assign the variable to the loop counter and use `File.Exists`:

```
List<yourType> missingFiles = new List<yourType>();
string path;

for (var i = 0; i<length; i++) {
   path = "path\" + i + ".wav";
   if (!File.Exists(path) {
       missingFiles.Add(path);
   }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx